# Cakephp control submenu

Tags: cakephp

I am using CakePhp 2.5, I do write a controller called `certificate`, and I do not want any submenu to appear at the view for the `activate` method from this controller.

I do already write an empty submenu named `activate.ctp` into the `elements/submenu/certificate` folder but the submenu which appears is another submenu from another controller.

```
<?php

$submenu = Configure::read('App.Menu.children.service.children.certificate.children');
Configure::write('App.Menu.Submenu', array('class'=>'nav nav-tabs','children'=>$submenu));
```

How can I control which submenu appears?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use [View Blocks](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#using-view-blocks).

Comment: Thank you Dave, the set solve this problem: `$this->set(array('submenu'=>'certificate'));`